# Meryの青い線の外し方

Tags: エディタ

テキストエディターにMeryを使用しています。
画面上部の目盛りの箇所をうっかり押してしまった以降、青い縦線が入り、入力文字がその縦線から改行されるようになりました。

この設定を解除するにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「指定文字数で折り返し」機能が有効になっています (改行されているわけではありません)。

以下の画像で表示されているツールバーのボタン、または <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> のホットキーで切り替えができます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]